# Why does the output look like this?

Tags: c, struct, bit-manipulation

I have a c program below, I would like to send out a 32 bit message in a particular order Eg.0x00000001.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct  test
{
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char buf[4];
    struct test* ptr=(struct test*)buf;
    ptr->a=0x0000;
    ptr->b=0x0001;
    printf("%x %x\n",buf[0],buf[1]); //output is 0 0
    printf("%x %x\n",buf[2],buf[3]); //output is 1 0
    return 0;
}
```

Then I test it by print out the values in char array. I got output in the above comments. Shouldn't the output be 0 0 and 0 1? since but[3] is the last byte? Is there anything I missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cause its little endian. Read this:
[Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

For translating them into network order, you have to use `htonl` (host-to-network-long) and `htons` (host-to-network-short) translating functions. After you receive, you need to use `ntohl` and `ntohs` functions to convert from network to host order. The order which your bytes are placed in the array depends on the way how did you put them in memory. If you put them as four separate short bytes, you will omit endianness conversion. You may use `char` type for this kind of raw bytes manipulations.

Comment: so how is the message looks like when I send out using sendto() from socket.h? It will be 0x00000001 or 0x00000100 ?

Comment: @cjk: you need to use `htons` for sending, it spares knowing the exact endianness for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your system stores numbers as [Little Endians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Answer (score 0):

Windows keeps the data as "little endian" so the bytes are reversed. 
See [Endiannes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_endian) for more info.